# How to safeguard or track pointer crashes easily?

Tags: c++, pointers

I found that the code often crashes when a pointer is used before being assigned validly, for example:

```
MyType* p = 0;
p->foo(); // crashes because p is not assigned.
```

To safeguard if, I usually add an assert statement before using a pointer, such as

```
assert(p);
```

But it is also easy to forget to add the assertion. Any better way to do the safeguard? Or any tools to help to locate the crash on the user's code when it happens?

I in fact use smart pointers a lot to own a data. A raw pointer is just used for reference. For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<Model> p;

class View
{
public:
    View(Model* model = 0) : m_model(model) {}

    void setModel(Model* model) {m_model = model;}
    Model* model() const {return m_model;}

private:
    Model* m_model;
};
```

The problem is still there when I forget to set model for the view. In a large code, it is so easy to forget to do it.

Comment: You use naked pointer a lot? my practice is to use reference though. If use pointer, use smart pointer instead.

Comment: The chrash is not because "p is not assigned". You explicitly assign it, but you assign an invalid address which when you dereference it leads to _undefined behavior_. And in the case of dereferencing the `NULL` pointer this often (but not always, undefined behavior and all that) leads to a crash.

Comment: Please see my post for smart pointer use.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Modified my post to be more rigorous in expressing.

Comment: This seems like a design problem. to me In my opinion, a view always has a model associated with it, otherwise it's useless. It may have an *empty* model associated with it, but the empty model should still be a model. Therefore, I'd say that your problem is that your `View` constructor does not explicitly require a valid `Model`.

Comment: @us2012 I think pointer is more flexible in this case. You can construct a view before a model and change model for view easily.

Comment: I'm *not really* arguing against the pointer per se (although it complicates the issue), I'm just saying that it may not be no pointer or an invalid pointer. You can still change it later, and yes, you can construct the view before the model that will have the required data, but even before that, the view should have a model (eg an empty one). That's just my 2 cents though.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tool for this sort of thing is valgrind.  During development you run your program like `valgrind myProg...` and it tells you about invalid memory accesses, leaks, and other things.

But as for adding an assertion that the pointer is not null before dereferencing, that seems a little unnecessary if as you say the program crashes upon null dereference anyway.  Adding the assert might make the reason for the crash slightly easier to track, but maybe you have a deeper problem (i.e. general overuse or misuse of raw pointers).

Comment: Even though asserting right before a call might be somewhat pointless, I would encourage to use asserts to validate any parameter passed to a method so that errors are caught right away.

Comment: I suppose, though I would usually just try to avoid writing functions in C++ that require a non-null raw pointer (use a reference or something instead).